# Get the data of bacrCode from NFT10 Pilot Pro lazer beam width (without camera ) using react-native/Expo

Tags: android, react-native, barcode, barcode-scanner

I have react-native android application used to read the barcod of product ,(i want using only the lazer reader) the barcode is alrady read by the terminal and it can be put on the Text input i mean if i have 3 Text and the cursor where in the first one the bacr code is set the . The problem is that i want a method to capture the data(barcode) before put it in the Text component in order to do some manipulation. Again i am not using the camera the terminal that i am using  NFT10 Pilot Pro

i tried a have a look in expo i didn't see any package or labrilr tha have inter action with lazer reader